# How do know if a Markov chain converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose that $X_n$ is a Markov chain on the states $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with transition matrix: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 \\ 
 1/5 & 1/5 & 1/5 & 1/5 & 1/5 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have been asked to determine whether $X_n$ converges almost surely or in $L^1$? How do I know whether these statements are true?

When I think of convergence of a Markov chain, I think of the stationary distribution (if it's ergodic) but I'm not sure if this is right.. could someone please provide some hints?

Comment: What is the initial distribution of the Markov chain?

Comment: We were also told that $X_0 = i$ for $0 < i < 4$?

Comment: Looks like all states are transient except states 0 and 4, and once we get to one of those we infinitely bounce between them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tau=\inf\{n>0: X_n\in\{0,4\}\}$. Because $P_{04}=P_{40}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ are transient, it is clear that $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n=\tau}^\infty \{X_n\in\{0,4\}\}\right) =1. $$
Moreover, if $N$ is a positive integer such that $X_N=0$, then $X_{N+2k}=0$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ with probability $1$ and similarly if $M$ is a positive integer such that $X_M=4$, then $X_{M+2k}=4$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ with probability $1$. It follows that
$$
\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left\{X_n = 0\right\} \right)
$$
while
$$
\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\{X_n = 4\right\} \right),
$$
so $X_n$ does not converge almost surely. By a similar argument it is clear that $X_n$ cannot converge in $L_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How did you arrive at the conclusion that "if $N$ is a positive integer such that $X_N = 0$, then $X_{N+2k} = 0$ for $k=1,2,3,...$ with probability 1, and similarly if $M$ is a positive integer such that $X_M = 4$ then $X_{M+2k} = 4$ for $k=1,2,3,...$ with probability 1"? Why are you adding $2k$?

Comment: Conditioned on $\{X_N=0\}$, we have $\mathbb P(X_{N+1}=4)=1$, $\mathbb P(X_{N+2}=0)=1)$, and so on.